Python) tf.keras.utils.audio_dataset_from_directory does not return correct labels
I am trying to study the code from [a tensorflow tutorial on audio recognition].(https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/simple_audio) But it seems the tf.keras.utils.audio_dataset_from_directory() function does not output labels corresponding to the correct data. Let me extract some of the relevant codes from the tutorial:
First, setting seed and downloading the data.
# Set the seed value for experiment reproducibility.
seed = 42
tf.random.set_seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)

DATASET_PATH = 'data/mini_speech_commands'

data_dir = pathlib.Path(DATASET_PATH)
if not data_dir.exists():
  tf.keras.utils.get_file(
      'mini_speech_commands.zip',
      origin="http://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/mini_speech_commands.zip",
      extract=True,
      cache_dir='.', cache_subdir='data')

Then split that data into train and validation data using tf.keras.utils.audio_dataset_from_directory(), and squeeze it.
train_ds, val_ds = tf.keras.utils.audio_dataset_from_directory(
    directory=data_dir,
    labels = "inferred",
    batch_size=64,
    validation_split=0.2,
    seed=0,
    output_sequence_length=16000,
    subset='both')

def squeeze(audio, labels):
  audio = tf.squeeze(audio, axis=-1)
  return audio, labels

train_ds = train_ds.map(squeeze, tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.map(squeeze, tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

However, when I iterate through train_ds with something like the following code, it always prints out the EXACT same list of labels despite the example audio being different on every iteration. Of course the label does not fit the audio.
for example_audio, example_labels in train_ds.take(1):
  print(example_audio)  #the example_audio tensor is different every time i run this block
  print(example_labels)  #the example_labels is always the same (and incorrect)

I cannot turn shuffle off when using audio_dataset_from_directory() bc then training dataset would not contain audio samples of all the possible words.
I have also tried something like train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(train_ds), seed=None, reshuffle_each_iteration=False) to no avail.
It would be incredibly helpful if anyone could figure out the reason behind label and audio not matching. Or at least the reason behind why only the audio is being shuffled, and not the labels.  Please tell me if I'm missing anything or didn't explain something enough, I'm just getting started on this field of study. Thank you in advance.

I ran your code on colab and got different labels for train_ds for every iteration of ds_train.take(1). Is there any rule on how to know when the audio and label are miss-matching? What is your TF version?

I tried it both on 2.16.1 and 2.15.0, because colab outputted some weird (but ignorable) warnings when getting the data on 2.16. But that’s so strange cuz i swear i have resetted runtime several times and retried on both versions only to get the same results… I assume you used 2.16 and above? I will try again with the most recent version again tmrw, this is really helpful though

ok figured it out, it was some of the pip installs i did before the code that somehow messed things the hell up.... For some reason if I do the pip installs written in the tutorial code things go haywire, everything works perfectly well if I don't execute that part. thanks @mhenning very much

No problem, glad you could solve this. I used the default TF version on colab (2.15 atm I think), as I find 2.16 still unstable in some parts (which your comment reinforces).
